# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in E:\i\todolist-nithishtry\views\list.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: node.js, backend, ejs

**code:**

```
<% newitems.forEach(function(item){%>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <p>
      <%= item.name %>
    </p>
  </div>

  <% });%>
```

**by using for loop i got the required output
when i tried to use for each loop i got error**

code used for for loop

```
   <%for(var i=0; i<newitems.length; i++){%>
          <div class="item">
          <input type="checkbox"  >
          <p><%= newitems[i].name %></p></div>
        <%}%>
```

Comment: The code with `forEach` works for me. Can you post more details about the error?

Comment: Thanks @HeikoTheißen actually code was working fine .Error was in Extension (Preitter) while i pressed  **ctrl+s**  it automatically made some changes .

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on my end. Check out the submit button and change the value to value="<%=listTitle%>". hope this helps